# Help sizing of lug attachment flange/plate?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, structures

Apologies for the crude drawing attached, but here goes. Given Fx, Fy, and Fz loads applied at the lug hole, I've distributed the loading into each of the 6 fasteners to size them. I've also sized the lug itself using the airforce lug sizing method.

But now I'm trying to size the portion of the lug fitting that I've labeled as "lug flange" and am kind of hitting a wall. I could throw this into FEM for sizing, but I'm thinking to size it by hand, I could separately determine the bending moments/torsion created in the x, y, and z directions about the bolt group center. But I’m lost as to what the next step would be. I’m mainly interested in sizing the thickness of the plate.

[image: Lug flange drawing]

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is very similar to the base plate on a column. AISC has a design guidebook for this: https://www.aisc.org/Design-Guide-1-Base-Plate-and-Anchor-Rod-Design-Second-Edition